# GoogleApiClient Node is null

Tags: android, wear-os, google-api-client

I'm writing an Android Wear app and I want to make the wear device start an intent on the phone when a button is clicked.

To do this, I've first set up the connection to the GoogleApiClient like this

```
 googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        googleApiClient.connect();
```

Then on button click the function sendMessage is run. This is the function

```
private void sendMessage(){
        if(mNode != null && googleApiClient != null && googleApiClient.isConnected()){
            Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(
                    googleApiClient, mNode.getId(),HELLO_WORLD_WEAR_PATH, null).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(MessageApi.SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {
                            if(!sendMessageResult.getStatus().isSuccess()){
                                Log.e("TAG", "Failed to send message with status code: " + sendMessageResult.getStatus().getStatusCode());
                            }
                            else{
                                Log.e("TAG", "Success");
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
        else {
            Log.e("TAG","No nodes" + mNode);

        }
    }
```

The problem is that the function goes into the else statement of sendMessage which means mNode is null. mNode is a variable of type Node.

To get the node, I have this function

```
private void resolveNode() {
        Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes) {
                for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
                    mNode = node;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I've connected my phone with the Android Wear Virtual Device in Android Studio.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

When you call googleApiClient.connect(), the connection takes a short amount of time and this call does not block. So you need to wait until the connection succeeds with a call to onConnected() before you do any further calls.

Next, when you call resolveNode(), the mNode variable is not set instantly. The setResultCallback is executed a short time later, and so you should not call sendMessage() until the result is processed.

So you need to ensure proper ordering for everything here.

(Edit)

After going through the comments, it turns out the problem was caused by the connection to Google Play Services failing. This was because the emulator used was an old API 20 device, which has an old version of Google Play Services. Using the latest API 22 emulator will resolve the issue.

Comment: I have put my code here http://pastebin.com/wLywc9WP 
If I understand you correctly, I think the order is good already. Or am I missing something?

Comment: What is happening inside resolveNode()? How many nodes are being returned and why are you storing only the last one?

Comment: Also, what play-services-wearable library are you using in build.gradle? Make sure it is version 7.5 or later on both the wearable and the phone side, otherwise it runs in a compatibility mode for when only one Android Wear devices were supported.

Comment: Also, are you getting any exceptions in your adb logcat output? It might be that you are hitting an exception by doing something on the wrong thread.

Comment: I got the resolve node function from another question on this site. I'll look into that.
As for the play-services-wearable library, it is version 7.5 on both the wearable and phone side.

Comment: No, no exceptions. Just the logs I put in the code. I just put log in both the onConnected and onConnectionFailed and it logs the onConnectionFailed log. So something is wrong with connecting to the GoogleApiClient

Comment: You should print out the error reason in onConnectionFailed, and it will then tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I logged connectionResult and it gave me this
'ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null}'

Comment: That error means that your wearable has an older version of Google Play Services on it. For example, you may have used SDK 7.5 in your build.gradle, but the wearable has only 7.3. Make sure your watch is paired with your phone, and worst case scenario try to resync all apps to make sure Play Services gets updated.

Comment: I'm using the Virtual Wear Device in Android Studio on API 20. I'll try another one and will let you know how that went. Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: Did it on API 22 and it works like a charm now. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try with this to get Node

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).await();
                for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()){
                    MessageApi.SendMessageResult resultMessage = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), ID_PATH, BYTES HERE).await();

                    if (resultMessage.getRequestId() == MessageApi.UNKNOWN_REQUEST_ID) {
                        Log.e("Message failed", ".......");
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: Should I replace the resolveNode function with this?

Comment: This function makes sure than variable 'nodes' receives some connection from mGoogleApiClient through of NodeApi.getConnectedNodes() and await until this happens. Then you can call MessageApi.sendMessageResult and put the node given in the for.