# Why am I getting "GoogleApiClient must not be null" when attempting to connect wear and Android app?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I'm following along with this tutorial, attempting to get my wear app and mobile app communicating.

https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/a-guide-to-the-android-wear-message-api/152

I think some part of the solution must be omitted, however, because I keep getting this crash:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
                  Process: com.webiphany.wearsync, PID: 27299
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: GoogleApiClient must not be null
                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zzb(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzv$zza.<init>(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.wearable.internal.zzm.<init>(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.wearable.internal.zzcb$2.<init>(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.android.gms.wearable.internal.zzcb.getConnectedNodes(Unknown Source)
                      at com.webiphany.wearsync.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:61)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

My wear and mobile apps are here:

https://github.com/xrd/WearSync

The relevant connection code for the wear app is here:

https://github.com/xrd/WearSync/blob/master/wear/src/main/java/com/webiphany/wearsync/MainActivity.java#L75

```
private void initGoogleApiClient() {
    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder( this )
            .addApi( Wearable.API )
            .build();

    mApiClient.connect();
}
```

The connection code for the android app is here:

https://github.com/xrd/WearSync/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/webiphany/wearsync/MainActivity.java#L79

```
private void setupDataLayer() {
        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected: " + connectionHint);
                        // Now you can use the Data Layer API

                        sendMessage( START_ACTIVITY, "" );
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended: " + cause);
                    }
                })
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: " + result);
                    }
                })
                // Request access only to the Wearable API
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .build();

    }
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?﻿

Comment: When in your flow are you getting this error? Or what action are you performing that is causing the crash? If I had to guess you're not fulling having mApiClient initialized before trying to access it. Your setupDataLayer method is called after setting up the listener for the fab which means it's possible for the events to be called out of order. You also aren't connecting in the setupDataLayer which is necessary.

Comment: Yes, I was not properly initializing the mApiClient. I did that, but I am not get getting the data inside the wear app.

Comment: So in my experience, it isn't as nice as you'd like it to be. How are you testing it? Do you have the devices hooked up correctly? It sounds silly but  this is, in my opinion, entirely too difficult.

Comment: The devices are connected according to the Android Wear companion app (both indicate connected and I followed the adb commands to get it that way). I believe it is correct. But, troubleshooting this is baffling me.

Comment: Do you have blutooth debugging enabled and all the setup on the companion app for that? Were you prompted to authorize the connection? Sorry for all the question - I fought for an insane amount of time over this exact issue and am trying to pin point your disconnect.

Comment: Make sure that the line `mApiClient.connect();` appears after `mApiClient` has been instantiated. As stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31328056/5832311), the connection takes a short amount of time and this call does not block when you call `googleApiClient.connect()`. Wait until the connection succeeds with a call to `onConnected()` before you do any further calls. `NullPointerException` is thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. You may refer with this [related issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866837).